# Rudimentary caching not working in a Google App Engine application

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-datastore

I'm making a blog using Google App Engine, which for now just allows me to post entries and see them listed out. I was following the Web Development course by Steve Huffman on Udacity where he showed a simple caching technique to decrease the database queries. Here's my code (which he instructed):

```
CACHE = {}
def top_entries():
    key = 'top'
    # logging.error(CACHE)
    if key in CACHE:
        entries = CACHE[key]
    else:
        logging.error("DB QUERY")
        entries = db.GqlQuery('select * from Entries order by created desc limit 10')
        entries = list(entries)
        CACHE[key] = entries
    return entries

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        entries = top_entries()
        self.response.write(render_str('mainpage.html', entries=entries))
```

`mainpage.html` is just the main page that lists the 10 most recent entries.

Basically, `CACHE` is a dictionary that stores a key that identifies a particular database query (in this case, listing out the top 10 entries) and on further calls to the same query, the application simply looks in that dictionary without making a database call.

What SHOULD happen is this:

1. I load the page for the first time and `DB QUERY` is printed on my console since it's a database call. The result of the query is stored in `CACHE`.
2. I reload and `DB QUERY` isn't printed since the cache has the key.

The above DOES happen but only if I have a fresh new tab to work on. If I already have a tab where I was working on this app, and I shut down the server, reboot it and then try reloading the page again, the above doesn't work. What happens is that step 1 happens twice and then step 2. It seems like the key isn't stored in the `CACHE` the first time I reload the page, but on the second time.

Here's the console log if the above paragraph is hard to follow:

The first time I boot the server and start working on a fresh tab:

```
PS C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN> python `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py' 'C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\Udacity\Web Development\Blog Project'
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:04,000 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:06,525 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53305
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:06,545 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:06,552 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2016-06-16 09:01:15,358 blog.py:134] DB QUERY
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:15,529 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1849
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:17,984 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1849
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:45,944 shutdown.py:45] Shutting down.
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:46,040 api_server.py:648] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:46,042 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
```

And this is what happens when I don't open a fresh tab but start working on the old tab.

```
PS C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN> python `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py' 'C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\Udacity\Web Development\Blog Project'
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:56,470 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:58,637 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53318
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:58,651 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-06-16 14:31:58,657 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2016-06-16 09:02:08,336 blog.py:134] DB QUERY
INFO     2016-06-16 14:32:08,526 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1849
ERROR    2016-06-16 09:02:12,538 blog.py:134] DB QUERY
INFO     2016-06-16 14:32:12,684 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1849
INFO     2016-06-16 14:32:16,822 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1849
INFO     2016-06-16 14:32:21,428 shutdown.py:45] Shutting down.
INFO     2016-06-16 14:32:21,430 api_server.py:648] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2016-06-16 14:32:21,430 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
```

`DB QUERY` gets printed out twice instead of once. I can't think of any reason why it would behave this way. (Maybe because of my browser cookies?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are caching at instance level and you can have number of instances or an instance can be recycled (*shut down*) and a new one instantiated on a request.

Try to use Memcache if you want to share cache between instances:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/

You can combine both approaches (instance cache + memcache)

Comment: But the video didn't have any such thing and it worked perfectly. Maybe because GAE changed functionalities?

Comment: Nope, this has always been the case.  Each instance is independant, and therefore the cache you defined is instance specific.  If you have a low uitilisation site instances may get shut down quickly and you will have no cache.  Use memcache as per the answer.  This is how traditional appengine has worked since it's release in 2008.

Comment: Okay, forgive me, because I'm new to this. But what is an instance exactly? Is an instance created whenever I load/reload the page?

Comment: You can treat an instance as an independent virtual machine or just as an independent server. When a new request comes to GAE it check if there is available free instances. If there is free one it dispatch request to it. If not it starts a new instance and dispatch request to the new one.

This is a good overview: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-instances-are-managed